# Windows 10 destroyed Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1

I am running Windows 10 on a laptop.  I connected a second disk that had Windows 8.1 installed on it.  I rebooted Windows 10 with the Windows 8.1 disk still attached it decided to scan and repair the Windows 8.1 drive:

"Scanning and repairing drive (E:)"

It scanned and repaired for a long time (about 2 hours), then it booted to Windows 10 normally.  BUT, now the Windows 8.1 drive won't boot anymore.  Windows 10 seems to have destroyed it.  When I try to boot from the Windows 8.1 drive it goes immediately into automatic repair and then says:

"Automatic Repair couldn't repair your PC"

I tried all of the options including opening the command prompt and running:

```
bootrec /fixMBR
bootrec /Fixboot
bootrec /rebuildBCD
```

but nothing works.  Also, some files and directories appear to be missing.

What has happened, how do I fix it, and why would Windows 10 do that to Windows 8.1?

Comment: “You can't "cd" to it using a command prompt” – you did change the drive first, using `X:↵`, right? The Command Prompt has multiple working directories, one per drive.

Comment: I see. Perhaps ignore that part then. I'll amend the question.

Comment: Why did your try to scan and repair the drive? Was it damaged?

Comment: No, Windows 10 just did it automatically.  There was nothing wrong with the drive

Comment: You could have skipped the scan but if It happened it needed it